# Is there any reason to open a chest from a lower arena as opposed to the same chest from a higher arena?

Tags: clash-royale

Like the question states, is there any reason why I should open a chest from arena X over a chest from arena X+1? The chest from the higher arena will give you more cards and coins than the lower arena.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **no**.
The only reason to open the *Arena X* chests would be that you're out of *Arena X+1* chests. Maybe if the higher chest is a gold one and you're saving it for the night or work day.

You many want to clear them out of the way at some point to make room for better ones, but if you're constantly getting just as many chests as you need, I'd postpone opening the lower level ones.

Of coures, they are in your inventory. I'll propably open them at *some* point anyways. Maybe that time you fall to the lower Arena. Maybe that one day you just don't feel like playing.

Comment: The only reason, as you mention, is if you want to open a quicker chest (pretty much only Silver), to save a longer open time chest (Gold +) for a long time away from play.  In my experience I almost never need more than 2 slots free. 1 in case I get a Gold I want to save for later, and one active constantly cycled slot.  The other slots are still useful if you flat can't play though - for pop in/pop out.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to go the other way though. Yes you should open arena 3 chests if you are n arena 4. You need to precious room for Arena 4 chests. I've lost more than one Arena 4 and then get demoted to 3 because I was full ... Moreover I've found that I need 4 slots to fully make sure I'm always opening a chest and playing for crowns in the allocated 24h, while making sure I don't play games when I'm full. Please check my other answers as to why this is important.

Comment: This may depend on your playstyle, but I'd think you'd get _just as much_ free space by opening the Arena 4 chests _and_ more content. Assuming the chests are both the same value, most likely Silver.

Answer (score 1):

**Some might want lower Arena Cards.** In Arena 1, for example, there are only 6 Epics. In Arena 8, there are almost 20. So there are better chances to get a specific Card.